# Looking for convenient way to find CPU number running current script

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, cpu

I want to implement a simple demo script that prints the name of the host and the number of the CPU running the script.

`hostname -s` takes care of the first part of the output.  Is there a similarly convenient way to get the CPU number?

(I understand that, in general, a process may comprise multiple threads, which may run on multiple CPUs.  Here, however, I assume that the script runs on a single thread.)

Comment: What Unix are you using? AFAIK, a process may be jumping between CPUs as its time slices are scheduled. Also, scripts usually make heavy use of external commands, and there's absolutely no guarantee that these are scheduled on the same CPU as the script is currently running on.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Centos  (FWIW, I just added tags to reflect this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to Jesse_b's solution above, but requests the information for the script using its pid:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

host=$(hostname -s)                                                             
processor=$(ps -hp $$ -o psr)                                                   

echo "Script running on ${host} on processor ${processor}"
```

The `-h` option suppresses the header, the `-p $$` option selects the process with the given pid, and `$$` is the pid of the running script, and the `-o psr` option selects only the psr field – the processor to which the process is currently assigned.

Comment: I originally was using `$$` in my script however I believe this is not the `pid` of the script but the instead of the current process.  So in your script I believe you are only showing the cpu id of the `ps -hp` process and not the overall script.  Also `pgrep $(basename $0)` will return the `pid` of the script, it just so happens that the script `pid` is also a `ppid` or `pgid`

Comment: No, `$$` is the PID of the script, not of `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, although this script often runs on more than one thread.  I believe this is also not going to be super accurate because a script creates a process group. This is searching for the `ppid` and many of the commands within the script are going to create their own `pid` within that process group. So any command that has finished and closed, or any process started after the `ps -aF` line wont be captured.

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname -s
echo -e "Proccess:\t$(pgrep "$(basename $0)")"
echo -e "$(ps -aF | grep "$(pgrep $(basename $0))" | awk '{print "CPU:\t\t"$7}')"
```